# Ionic CodePush failure: no such file or directory, lstat './platforms/android/assets/www/'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I followed [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ClemMakesApps/ionic-framework-codepush-115b38d187fb), and even the [official ionic codepush example](https://github.com/Dellos7/example-cordova-code-push-plugin).

Both used the platforms/android/assets/www folder, but there is neither assets folder, nor www folder under platforms/android in my project.

Where I can solve this problem?

Comment: What commands are you running to generate the build and to release the code push deployment?

Comment: ionic cordova build android, I also tried ionic build, ionic cordova prepare android, all seem the same.

Comment: And for the deployment for code push?  Are you using the `release` command in the CLI or `release-cordova`?  https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push#releasing-updates

Comment: no. I didn't use release in CLI. the assets folder wan't there from the beginning.

Comment: I believe the assets location changed based on the cordova-android platform version you are using.  Maybe the code push plugin doesn't handle recent project structures well.  You could try downgrading the android platform version, or possibly explicitly telling code push where the assets are (`-c` param if using appcenter codepush CLI).

Answer (score 0):

I found the assets folder is located in /platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets when used --debug option in ionic cordova run. Or located in /platforms/android/app/src/main/assets w/o debug option.
I don't get why. But I think it should be documented at least.